# How to get GUID in android?

Tags: android

we are developing the application using the .Net webservice(soap protocal)  for that i need Pass GUID from android class.

in .Net we have statement like below 
    Guid myGuid1 = new Guid();

i need the similar functionality in Android , 
is there any way to make this kind of functionality in android code?

Regards,
Jeyavel N

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use the [`java.util.UUID`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html) class.

Comment: notice that guid generates letters in upper case while uuid in lower case

Answer (score 95):

Yes you should use UUID like the following code:

```
String  uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Comment: Note this gives you a type 4 UUID, which is just a random value. The `UUID` class can't generate type 1 UUIDs (time based).

Comment: Sorry, but idk where to add the uniqueID that is generated. Is there a function like "setGUID(parameter)"?

Answer (score 12):

We can use

```
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

An Instance ID or a GUID is scoped to the app that creates it, which prevents it from being used to track users across apps.For more information and significance please refer this link [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html)

Answer (score 2):

You will get UUID in Android,

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
String uuidInString = uuid.toString();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325105/how-to-create-uuid-from-string-in-android

Comment: This is essentially just repeating [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27753881/1402846).