# How to create UUID from string in android

Tags: android, uuid, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my app, I scan low energy Bluetooth for specific service uuid `2415`. To convert the string 2415 into uuid I am using `UUID serviceUUID = UUID.fromString("2415");` but at this line exception arises IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID 2415.

Please help me in this respect I would b very thankful to in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried combining your short UUID with the Bluetooth base UUID? I.e. `"00002415-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"`? (assuming that you meant `2415` hexadecimal)?

Comment: @Michael maybe make it an answer so more people can see it is the correct answer?

Comment: converted @Michael comment to a community wiki answer

Comment: "2415" is not an UUID, period. It's not even "short UUID". In this context, it's a fragment of an UUID.

Answer (score 35):

Using the class [UUID](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html)

An example like this:

```
 UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answer should be helpful. This gives you a random UUID which is not related to the problem of the OP.

Comment: I don't understand why people upvote this, yes it links to the correct class but it is not relevant to the question why in other platforms we can use CBUUID "140D" for example and in Android there is no baked in support for this.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question asked

Answer (score 23):

The accepted answer was provided in a comment by @Michael:

> Have you tried combining your short UUID with the Bluetooth base UUID?
>   I.e. "00002415-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"? (assuming that you meant
>   2415 hexadecimal)?

I'm converting that comment to an answer because I missed it first time I read through this thread.

Answer (score 17):

you can use

```
String str = "1234";
UUID uuid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(str.getBytes());

System.out.print(uuid.toString());
```

Comment: Although this might solve the problem, it is always good to add an explanation why/how this works.

Answer (score 14):

The confusion that may lead many people here is that you can use short code UUIDs to reference bluetooth services and characteristics on other platforms - for instance on iOS with [CBUUID](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBUUID_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)CBUUID).
On Android however, you must provide a full, 128-bit length UUID as specified in [RFC4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt).

The fix (as @Michael pointed out) is to prepend your 16bit or 32bit short UUID to the [base bluetooth UUID](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery). You can use these functions to make this a bit easier.

```
public static final String baseBluetoothUuidPostfix = "0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";

public static UUID uuidFromShortCode16(String shortCode16) {
    return UUID.fromString("0000" + shortCode16 + "-" + baseBluetoothUuidPostfix);
}

public static UUID uuidFromShortCode32(String shortCode32) {
    return UUID.fromString(shortCode32 + "-" + baseBluetoothUuidPostfix);
}
```

For example:

```
UUID uuid = uuidFromShortCode16("FFF0");
```

This creates a UUID object from `"0000FFF0-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"`.

Answer (score 10):

**Hope this will help**
To Convert short hand 16-bit uuid to 128 bit uuid you can use this template `"0000XXXX-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"`. here replace `XXXX` with your 16 bit uuid.
For example:
 In your use case 128 bit UUID will be `"00002415-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"`. 
and to get UUID from string you should use code like this 
`UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00002415-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");`
https://newcircle.com/s/post/1786/2016/01/04/bluetooth-uuids-and-interoperable-advertisements

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that your String "2415" might just have been straight-up converted from a long, because, as the others point out, "2415" is not close to resembling a UUID. If that is the case, then you should use the UUID constructor which takes two longs:

`uuid = new UUID(long mostSignificant, long leastSignificant)`

where you can retrieve those long values via

`uuid.getMostSignificantBits()`
`uuid.getLeastSignificantBits()`

So in your case, you might do something like `uuid = new UUID(2415,2415)`