# How to correctly use UUID.fromString method?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble, rxandroidble

I am trying to read/write these ble characteristics:

[image]

Right now, I'm trying to read **AA01***

I am using [this library](https://www.polidea.com/blog/RxAndroidBLE_the_most_Simple_way_to_code_Bluetooth_Low_Energy_devices/) to do it.

Here's my code:

```
private void connectToSensorTag(RxBleDevice rxBleDevice) {
    rxBleDevice.establishConnection(getApplicationContext(), false)
            .doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    int i = 0;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("AA01*")))
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    int i = 0;
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    int i = 0;
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(byte[] bytes) {
                    int i = 0;
                }
            });
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID: AA01*

I also tried the solutions from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325105/how-to-create-uuid-from-string-in-android) but nothing works. Same error.

Comment: That's not a UUID. UUID's look like this: 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier.

Comment: A UUID is supposed to be a 128 bit value, it must be somethinf like we get in Bluetooth Low Energy documentations. AA01 should be the starting of a long UUID (all other characters may be same). A UUID usually looks like 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000

Comment: You probably don't need to be using UUIDs at all but rather just reading a few bytes off the packet (two for the Object field and two for the Ambience).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the BLE specification there are two kinds of UUIDs.

- Fully qualified 128 bits long which are usually assigned for a specific vendor of the BLE device for non-standard functionality:
  `UUID.fromString("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");`
- Also fully qualified (but defined by standard) UUIDs which have the same prefix and postfix: `UUID.fromString("F000xxxx-0451-4000-B000-000000000000");`
  where `xxxx` is the place to fill the four characters you get from the SensorTag specification. For convenience the standard UUIDs are usually referenced with the four characters identifier.

Additionally if you're dealing with a SensorTag device you can checkout the library demo application that was shown on MCE^3 conference this year:

The talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aKfUGCxUDM

The demo application repository: https://github.com/dariuszseweryn/2016_MCE_Demo_RxAndroidBLE

I hope that will help you.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You must provide a full uuid:

```
UUID uid = UUID.fromString("f000aa01-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a faster `java.util.UUID.fromString()`, you can use [Fast-UUID-Parser](https://github.com/komamitsu/fast-uuid-parser)
 instead. It returns `java.util.UUID` and it's 4 times faster than `java.util.UUID.fromString()`.