# RxAndroidBle: Reading Pre-Defined GATT Characteristics

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, characteristics, rxandroidble

I have a BLE device with multiple characteristics addressed by default addresses as defined [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics)

Things like Manufacturer Name String, Hardware Revision String, Serial Number String etc.

Using the UUID class I've attempted several different ways to construct a UUID that RxAndroidBle would accept and read from these characteristics.

The one I though would work most was this:

```
UUID GATT_DSR1_MANUFACTURER_NAME = new UUID(0L, 0x2A29L);
```

but I just get back onError callbacks.

RxBleConnection.readCharacteristic only accepts UUID or a BluetoothGattCharacteristic which is created with a UUID...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Creating UUIDs**
(copied from [How to correctly use UUID.fromString method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38550124/how-to-correctly-use-uuid-fromstring-method/38564713#38564713) )

In the BLE specification there are two kinds of UUIDs.

- Fully qualified 128 bits long which are usually assigned for a specific vendor of the BLE device for non-standard functionality: UUID.fromString("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");
- Also fully qualified (but defined by standard) UUIDs which have the same prefix and postfix: <del>`UUID.fromString("F000xxxx-0451-4000-B000-000000000000");`</del> *`UUID.fromString("0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")`* where xxxx is the place to fill the four characters you get from the <del>SensorTag</del> *Bluetooth Core* specification. For convenience the standard UUIDs are usually referenced with the four characters identifier.

Your `0x2A29L` stands for `"2A29"` String as the xxxx.

**Obtaining BluetoothGattCharacteristic**

On Android there is no possibility to create a working `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` with a `UUID`. It is still possible to call `RxBleConnection.discoverServices()` and get it from the result though.